How to find the upper and lower bounds for slope and intercept in linear algebra?
I'm trying to make an algorithm for linear regressions where it will test every slope and intercept to find the perfect slope and intercept. From what I was taught, that is the standard way of making linear regressions. For that it would need an upper and lower bound for the slope and intercept. I don't really know how one gets those. How to find the upper and lower bounds?

There are standard formulas for slope and intercept for best fit $y=\alpha +\beta x$
